# Irreducible algebraic set

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm stuck on the following question:

Is the intersection of irreducible algebraic sets always an irreducible algebraic set?

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** : take a line and a conic in a plane. What can you say about the intersection in general ?

Comment: is it two points?

Comment: @JonathanBaram : Yes, so the answer is "no" in general.